# Access a TSV in scalding without schema

Tags: scala, scalding

I have a tab separated file (tsv) whose schema is not known to me and i want to remove the first column from every row using "Scalding".

I know that if the schema is known then i can use

```
val dataControlSchema = List('a,'b,'c,'d,'e,'f)
  Tsv("abc.tsv").read
  .discard('a)
  .write(Tsv("output1.tsv"))
```

but the problem is that i dont know the schema , maybe there would be 6 column or 7 or even more. BUT IT IS FIXED THAT I HAVE TO REMOVE THE 1ST COLOUMN .. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Scalding provides two kinds of API's

1. Fieled based API
2. Type-safe API

In this case you will have to use the type-safe API,

```
val fromFile: TypedPipe[ String ] = TypedPipe.from( TextLine("abc.tsv" ) )
fromFile
.map( _.split( "\t" ) )  // now should be TypedPipe[ Array[ String ] ]
.map( _.toList ) //  now should be TypedPipe[ List[ String ] ]
.map( _.drop( 1 ) ) // this should drop first string from the List
.map( _.mkString( "\t" ) ) // Now TypedList[ String ]
.write( TypedTsv( "output.tsv" ) )
```

Comment: Thanx a lot sir but it drops of the first character not the first column and it should be .write(TypedTsv("output.tsv"))

Comment: What's in your tsv file ?

Comment: This is working fine for me. Is your `tsv file` really tab-separated. If not then replace `"\t"` with your separator.

Comment: i get output as [Ljava.lang.String;@8c5ea2
[Ljava.lang.String;@198defc
[Ljava.lang.String;@1579a30

Comment: Well... that's because the `Array.toString` does not work as `List.toString`... convert `Array[ String ]` to `List[ String ]` before dumping to your output... as I have added now.

Comment: input is 
sanchit\tgrover\tis\ta\ta\tgood\tboy
saif\tullah\tis\ta\ta\tgood\tboy
but it gives output as 
List(grover, is, a, good, boy)
List(pant, is, a, good, boy)
but desired output is 
grover\tis\ta\tgood\tboy
ullah\tis\ta\tgood\tboy

Comment: Well... convert back to string with `_.mkString( "\t" )`, added in the answer.

Comment: sir i wish to learn scalding properly, can you suggest me where to start ?

Comment: There is nothing special about Scalding, its just Scala. Just keep programming in Scala and you will keep getting better at Scala and hence at Scalding... but there are some open source books... One is https://github.com/scalding-io/ProgrammingWithScalding

Answer (score 0):

Awesome ans by @sarveshKsingh. just a bracket missing at the end of .write

val fromFile: TypedPipe[ String ] = TypedPipe.from( TextLine("abc.tsv" ) )

```
fromFile

.map( _.split( "\t" ) )  // now should be TypedPipe[ Array[ String ] ]

.map( _.toList ) //  now should be TypedPipe[ List[ String ] ]

.map( _.drop( 1 ) ) // this should drop first string from the List

.map( _.mkString( "\t" ) ) // Now TypedList[ String ]

.write( TypedTsv( "output.tsv" )) // a bracket was missing.
```